# How to extract information from Google Click ID (gclid)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

There is some way to get campaign information like source, name, medium, keyword, etc from the given gclid parameter that came in the query string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably not.  It contains a timestamp, and two other integers.  However we couldn't match those other integers to any campaign, adword, or keyword ID that we found in the Adwords backend.

We've written about how [gclids are encoded](http://blog.deed-poll-office.org.uk/articles/decoding-gclid-parameter) (and how you can go about decoding them for yourself).

Comment: Is this still the case? The php script at the command returned garbage and `protoc --decode_raw` and `blackboxprotobuf` both failed to decode the value.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#click), it has plenty of information about a click, referenced by `ClickId`. The easiest way to access report data is via [AdWords scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/reports).

Comment: Do you have access to an AdWords script that performs this function?

Comment: @FullDecent Not an adwords script but we have api access and you can download [click performance report](https://www.adnabu.com/products/report/creation) from our website

Comment: You also can use https://www.Awql.me to query easily the click performance report table. Easier than an Adwords script if you just want to make a query

Comment: The trouble with this is that you can only access one day of data at a time. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/5oa-AXXrMHk

Answer (score 1):

No, it's an opaque ID dynamically added to AdWords ad destination URLs at the time they are served. Only AdWords can later associate that ID back to a particular campaign, ad group, keyword, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can link you Adwords account and Google Analytics account to get this information into Google Analytics.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en

Comment: They are already linked. The goal is to have more then just a number in Analytics, getting the campaign what user came from I can link that information to the generated lead and work if much more data for ads performance associating the conversion to the information received in the form on the page. I can know that all conversions that came from campaign X have marked some option Y in the form, then redesign the creatives for a better UX and all other kinds of improvements based on real data.

Comment: You may be able to do what you want by adding Google Analytics events to your form submission and creating a goal or goals in GA.