# How to use google click id (GCLID) to extract AdWords Campaign, Ad Group, Keyword, Ad, etc

Tags: google-ads-api

I tried searching for api which can help in extracting AdWords Campaign, Ad Group, Keyword, Ad, Keyword, etc.. from Google Click ID (gclid), but I end up with Click Performance Reports. Well it wont solve my requirement completely.
So is there any way to use "gclid" in adwords to extract data.
Any public API would be of great use.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why the Click Performance report does not satisfy your requirements? It provides all of the fields that you have listed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576091/how-to-extract-information-from-google-click-id-gclid

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old but I wanted to share: Google AdWords has an API.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start

Check out the PHP Library on Github.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib

Comment: Are there any updated methods since the AdWords API sunset?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Ads V13, you need to do query in click_view resource, Here you can check one [example](https://iamhimanshu.medium.com/how-to-fetch-gclid-google-click-id-using-the-google-ads-v13-api-6cb89f5b066d) to query in click_view.

[Google Query builder](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v13/campaign_query_builder) will help you to generate the SQL query with Ads Campaign, Ads Groups etc.

Answer (score 0):

Gclid is exactly that - Click ID. With this, you can fetch Click Performance report [like you have done](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/click-performance-report). It contains CampaignID, AdgroupID and Criteria which has KeywordID. Then with these ID's, you can fetch appropriate reports which contain any additional information you may want!